ASP.NET Core Cloud Published Application creating a TraceUpload folder that does not seem to be getting updated with the current dependency versions
When publishing my application it keep producing a TraceUpload zip folder that is showing an older version of System.Text.Json and it's causing me security issues. Even though my packages are fully up to date (9.0.0) it is still only showing:
"System.Text.Json": "6.0.4"


And yet my solution has the correct and up-to-date package:

How can I get this resolved so that the TraceUpload zip is being updated properly on publish?

Your screenshot indicates that the lower version of System.Text.Json is being pulled in via transitive dependencies. Have you tried updating Azure.Core and the ApplicationInsights profiler package (and anything else that depends on a lower version of System.Text.Json)?

Would this be an update required in the solution or on the build pipeline? Editing: After looking at my nuget packages it's showing the ApplicationInsights.Profiler and and ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore are both fully up-to-date versions to their latest.

It would be a change in the solution. The app insights dependency that needs updating looks like it's ...Profiler.Uploader,  not the main app insights package.

That isn't even a nuget package in my project. I have no idea where this would be coming from. I have combed through the other packages and theyre all up to date and none appear to have a dependency on that version of Text.Json

Does your project explicitly reference any version of System.Text.Json? If not, try adding that.

Firt, you need to find all transitive dependencies for System.Text.Json, in .NET 9 there a new command for this purpose called: dotnet nuget why
So run this command in solution root (*.sln path):
 dotnet nuget why System.Text.Json

The output is something like this:

You will find out what those packages reference to a lower version on System.Text.Json internally, as far as I can see in your packages, can be these 2 packages:

Azure.Storage.Blobs
Azure.Core

Try to use the latest version of the above packages and run the dotnet nuget why command again to check the versions, if the problem is still there then the solution is to overwrite the package version of System.Text.Json explicitly like this in all *.crproj:
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="9.0.0" ExcludeAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>

